# Make generated divs that are created every few seconds fall down screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adobe-edge

So I'm working in Adobe Edge for school atm, and I'm trying get divs that are being created every 2 seconds to fall down the screen. Bear with me, I'm new to javascript :)

This is the code to generate the div, but I have no idea how to target a div after and make it fall down. I've tried using a setTimeout and target elements with id=block but it only makes the first div generated fall down the screen.

```
SpawnBlock();

        function SpawnBlock()
        {
            UpdateBlock();
            setTimeout(SpawnBlock, 2000);
        }

        function UpdateBlock()
        {
            var block = document.createElement("div");
            block.style.width = "20px";
            block.style.height = "20px";
            block.style.background = "white"
            block.style.top = "100px";
            block.style.left = Math.random() * 460 + "px";
            block.style.position = "absolute";
            block.id = "block";
            //block.speed = 0.5;
            sym.$("Stage").append(block);                
        }
```

sym.$("Stage") is the div assigned by Adobe Edge in which I'm working. 
After this I'll have to add collision to a ball that follows my mouse cursor and can jump ( think of the Winterbells game ).

This is what I have so far: http://student.howest.be/pieter-jan.vandenb1/crossdodger/Game.html

Comment: Did you try giving every block a different `id` and then use the `setTimeout` to let that specific block fall down? `id`'s are kind of ... identifiers (unique).

Comment: @jabbink I completely forgot about classes so instead of giving the block an id I gave it a classname. This makes every block drop, but I think it might still be better to give them an unique id because later on I'll have trouble with unit collision I guess ( figuring out with what block the ball is colliding ).

Answer (score 0):

first it suppose to be class='block' not id.  you can do two things 
1- create diferent id for each block , and create for each timeout targeting that id, or  target .block:last-child; to target last generated block.

Comment: I've managed to it to work by adding this code: http://pastebin.com/DHKyreEc. Right now this is how it looks:http://student.howest.be/pieter-jan.vandenb1/crossdodger/Game.html. I still have to do something about keeping the animation at a constant speed ( working with transit.js ) but I suppose that's sth to do with easing.